# How can I make only one task's li element have the completed class when clicked in a React todo list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello)) I’m just learning React and making the first todolist, and here’s the problem, I’m trying to make it so that when I click on the input of one task, the li of this task would have the completed class, but it appears for everyone, but it shouldn’t be like that, what’s my problem?[react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyecQ.png)[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilx3A.png)
[the first screen is from my ide, the second is from the browser]

Tried using this.state and this.setState first but didn't work, then did with useState but same

react todo-list:

```
const TodoList = ({ todoData }) => {
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ul className="todo-list">
      {todoData.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <li key={i} className={completed === false ? '' : 'completed'}>
            <div className="view">
              <input className="toggle" type="checkbox" onClick={() => setCompleted(true)}></input>
              <label>
                <span className="description">{item.description}</span>
                <span className="created">{item.created}</span>
              </label>
              <button className="icon icon-edit"></button>
              <button className="icon icon-destroy"></button>
            </div>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

app component:

```
const App = () => {
  const todoData = [
    { description: 'Completed task', created: 'created 17 seconds ago', done: true },
    { description: 'Editing task', created: 'created 5 minutes ago', done: false },
    { description: 'Active task', created: 'created 5 minutes ago', done: false },
  ];

  return <TodoApp todoData={todoData} />;
};
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please include code as text, not images.